# Active Record in CodeIgniter 2

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this code:

```
$places = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('places')
    ->where('postal_code',$search)
    ->limit($limit, $start)
    ->get()->result();
```

I want to know if is there something wrong, and which is the way to get a query with a simple where inside the query.

Answer (score 0):

Like this..

```
$places = $this->db->get_where('places',array('postal_code'=>$search),$limit,$start)->result();//outputs result in object format

 $places = $this->db->get_where('places',array('postal_code'=>$search),$limit,$start)->result_array();//outputs  result in array format
```

See more docs https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Hi Hikmat it seems works fine, but it gets also the fields with a null column, how I can do to get only the items with the field postal_code exist?

Comment: what is output of `print_r($places);`?

Comment: and what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I do it in other way, as I can see is there some issues to do a where and limit sentence in CodeIgniter in the same query.

So I do it directly in SQL

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE locality = '".$search."' LIMIT ".$start.",".$limit."";
$places = $this->db->query($query)->result();
```

Not nice, but it works.